# Suscpicious registry entry

Tags: windows

In HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxx\Software\Microsof\TATrial and  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsof\TATrial there are entries Default (no value set) InstallDate (733998) and UseCount (3). I do not have an antivirus on this machine because it's slow and am wondering if there is reason to be concerned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were to take a guess, I'd say that it had to do with some sort of software (possibly from Microsoft, but just as likely not) that you had installed a trial version of. The registry contents don't *appear* to be malicious; an install date and usage count isn't particularly insidious. If you're to be concerned, I'd think it would be for some other reason than this.

You're bound to find LOTS of registry entries you can't immediately place off-hand. That's sort of the nature of the registry.

Comment: just to point out it wasn't a typo that the key is in Microsof no Microsoft

Comment: Or at least not *your* typo :) -- Companies will frequently try to hide their own registry keys under Microsoft's name. This particularly makes sense in the context of tracking product trials, since deleting the key would probably allow you to re-trial the software.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it could be a malware. I have very little to go off of, but I found a spanish forum (google translated below):

http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=es&u=http://www.taringa.net/posts/info/3543215/Eliminar-Virus-Manualmente-y-Optimizar-la-PC.html&prev=/search%3Fq%3DHKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE%255CSOFTWARE%255CMicrosof%255CTATrial%26hl%3Den%26safe%3Dactive%26tbo%3Dd%26rls%3Dcom.microsoft:en-us:IE-Address%26biw%3D1280%26bih%3D706&sa=X&ei=i6L2UOyENpLW8gTs5YDoAg&ved=0CEcQ7gEwAg

Note specifically:

@ abinadar Hace 2 años

> to me the folder appears inside RUN, reg_Z default value not set. and
>   renunce, aparace the super antispyware you install. in the other there
>   is nothing.  but before the Microsoft folder, there is one called
>   microsof (without the t at the end) this is bad? one says the other
>   tatrial210 tareloc200

This person was noting the registry key called TATRIAL210 inside of "microsof" registry folder. A misspelling would more than likely be some form of malware.

**EDIT: http://forum.sysinternals.com/microsof-reg-entrys-3_topic4953.html
Possibly not virus. Are you using software called "Text aloud?"**